# Is there a finite constant C such that the Lebesgue measure satisfies $ m(A + B) ≤ C (m(A) + m(B))?$

Tags: real-analysis, inequality, lebesgue-measure

This is a homework question. I have been thinking of it for a while and had some idea, but I'm not so sure if I am on the right track or missing something.

For any two sets A,B $\subseteq R$, define A+B = {a+b:a $\in A$, b $\in B$}. Is there a finite constant C such that the Lebesgue measure satisfies $m(A + B) \leq C m(A) + m(B)$ whenever $A, B, A + B  \in$ Borel $\sigma$-alg?

========= update =========

I just noticed there is this counterexample:
When $A = (-\inf, a), B = (-\inf, b)$, $A + B = (-inf, a+b)$, and both sides of the inequality is infinity and thus not comparable.

========= old =========

I thought it would suffice to consider the case when A, B are of the form (a, b) (a < b $\in R$), as the Borel sigma algebra is constructed using open intervals, and $m(A) = inf\{\sum (b_i - a_i): A \subseteq \cup (a_i, b_i)\}$, where m is the Lebesgue measure.

For open intervals $A = (a_1, b_1), B = (a_2, b_2), A+B = (a_1+a_2, b_1+b_2),$ and the inequality in question is true for all $C \geq 1$.

My question is, is it correct to simple consider the case where A, B are both open intervals? I feel I'm missing something, ignoring some cases, but I have no idea what these cases could be.

Comment: If such a constant existed, it would follow that, whenever $A$ has Lebesgue measure zero, then $A+A$ has Lebesgue measure zero. Why don't you concentrate on trying to find a counterexample to that? E.g., a set $A$ of Lebesgue measure zero such that $A+A$ contains an interval?

Comment: An easier counterexample: $A=[0,1]$ and $B=\mathbb Z.$

Comment: Or just $A=[0,1]$ and $B-\{0,1,\dots,\lceil C\rceil\}.$

Comment: If $A$ is the Cantor set, then $m(A)=0$ and $A+A=[0,2].$

Comment: Hi @bof, thank you very much for your answer. I feel the first counterexample you give is similar to the one I wrote in my update in the sense that both sides of the inequality would be infinity, right? I am checking the canto set counterexample now

Comment: If $A=[0,1]$ and $B=\mathbb Z$ then $m(A+B)=m(\mathbb R)=\infty$ while $m(A)+m(B)=1+0=1.$ So just one side is $\infty.$

Comment: @bof You are right, thank you very much!